# Ruby compare activerecord with string width special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I want to search my `Person`'s model by `name`. It can be "Iñaki" or "Caneça" for this example´s sake. How can I do this without upper or down case concerns?

I tried: `Person.where("upper(name) = ?", name.upcase)` but that certainly doesn't do the job if I type IÑAKI or CANEÇA.

I'm aware of this code `.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')` suggested in some other answers, but how can I apply this here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complicated topic, but based on my *very limited* investigation:

- Some databases support UTF-8, default to UTF-8 and implement `upper` in a way that supports accented characters in some fashion. I think Postgres falls into that category
- Ruby, even as of 2.0, does not support accented characters for `String` in either upcase or downcase

The trickiest seems to be that the uppercase/lowercase relationship between characters varies from locale to locale (e.g. same lowercase character may map to different uppercase characters depending on locale).

In any event, while I saw a reference to UnicodeUtils gem, the following worked on my machine for the simple examples you provided:

```
Person.where("upper(name) = ?", name.mb_chars.upcase)
```

The `mb_chars` method is added to `String` by Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Is `encoding: utf8` in your config/database.yaml file? This may solve the problem.